# how to get the count(id) from the multiple tables using join query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to display count based on the id from multiple tables. for two tables it is working fine but for three tables it is not displaying data

this is my query for three tables it is not working

```
select r.req_id
     , r.no_of_positions
     , count(j.cand_id) as no_of_closure
     , count(cis.cand_id) 
from requirement r 
join joined_candidates j 
  on r.req_id=j.req_id
join candidate_interview_schedule cis 
  on cis.req_id=r.req_id 
where cis.interview_status='Interview Scheduled' 
group by r.req_id, r.no_of_positions;
```

Comment: No results mean 1 of two things: 1 Where clause criteria is excluding all data.  A join is being made and no matches on join criteria are found.  We don't have enough information to know what the problem is.  case sensitivity in the where clause?  Eliminate the where clause, do you get counts/results? If so upper both pieces and trim? `TRIM(UPPER(cis.interview_status))=UPPER('Interview Scheduled')`  For the join: Are you sure you have a req_ID that exists in all 3 tables?  We don't know what two tables worked.  That would aid in isolating the problem.

Comment: The req_id is different in different tables but I want to display all the req_id and null if the value doesn't match in other tables

Comment: Then you need perhaps you need to use a LEFT Join on the two tables so that if a req_ID doesn't exist in one of the two tables it will still be displayed.  Additionally the counts will be inflated if you these tables have 1:M relatioships so you may need to use a count over partition...

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed to left joins incase value doens't exist in a table
2. Changed count to use an window function so counts are not artificially inflated by joins
3. moved where clause to join criteria as on a left join, it would negate the null values, making it operate like a inner join.

..MAYBE...

```
SELECt r.req_id
     , r.no_of_positions
     , count(j.cand_id) over (partition by J.cand_ID) as no_of_closure
     , count(cis.cand_id) over (partition by cis.cand_id) as no_of_CIS_CNT
FROM  requirement r 
LEFT join joined_candidates j 
  on r.req_id=j.req_id
LEFT join candidate_interview_schedule cis 
  on cis.req_id=r.req_id 
 and  cis.interview_status='Interview Scheduled' 
GROUP BY  r.req_id, r.no_of_positions;
```

or perhaps... (if I can assume j.cand_ID and cis.cand_ID are unique)  also to eliminate artificial count increase due to 1:M joins

```
SELECt r.req_id
     , r.no_of_positions
     , count(distinct j.cand_id) as no_of_closure
     , count(distinct cis.cand_id) as no_of_CIS_CNT
FROM  requirement r 
LEFT join joined_candidates j 
  on r.req_id=j.req_id
LEFT join candidate_interview_schedule cis 
  on cis.req_id=r.req_id 
 and  cis.interview_status='Interview Scheduled' 
GROUP BY  r.req_id, r.no_of_positions;
```